# Programmatically accessing build.properties of a Java project through JDT API

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-pde

Is there a way to access programmatically the `build.properties` of a Java project through the JDT API? Something like `IJavaProject.getRawClasspath()` just for the `build.properties`?

If I have an `IProject`/`IJavaProject`, can I add a line with the JDT API like this (through JDT API calls):

Before:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
```

After:

```
source.. = src/,\
           xtend-gen/
output.. = bin/
```

Comment: This is a PDE object rather than JDT so any API is not going to in the JDT APIs.

Comment: So there are PDE calls that do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PDE object rather than JDT so you need to use the PDE APIs. There is very little documentation on the PDE APIs.

The build.properties is described by the `org.eclipse.pde.core.build.IBuildModel` interface. You get this using:

```
IProject project = ... project ...

IPluginModelBase base = PluginRegistry.findModel(project);

IBuildModel buildModel = PluginRegistry.createBuildModel(base);
```

You can get the entry for 'bin.includes' using

```
IBuildEntry entry = buildModel.getBuild().getEntry(IBuildEntry.BIN_INCLUDES);
```

The `addToken` method of `IBuildEntry` seems to be the way to add to the entry.

To save you need to check the model is an instance of `IEditableModel` and call the `IEditableModel.save` method.

```
if (buildModel instanceof IEditableModel) {
  ((IEditableModel)buildModel).save();
}
```